# How to unittest GPIO output value of raspberry pi in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-unittest

I am making Raspberry Pi program by using python.
I want to write `unittest` of my python code.
How can I get output status of `GPIO`?

test target class is bellow. I want to check outputs after calling stop, brake, rotateClockwise and rotateCounterClockwise.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
# moter management class, with like TA7291P
class MoterManager:
    def __init__(self, in1Pin, in2Pin):
        self.__in1Pin = in1Pin
        self.__in2Pin = in2Pin

    def stop(self):
        self.__offIn1()
        self.__offIn2()

    def brake(self):
        elf.__onIn1()
        self.__onIn2()

    def rotateClockwise(self):
        self.__onIn1()
        self.__offIn2()

    def rotateCounterClockwise(self):
        self.__offIn1()
        self.__onIn2()

    def __onIn1(self):
        GPIO.output( self.__in1Pin, True)
        print "In1 on"

    def __onIn2(self):
        GPIO.output( self.__in2Pin, True)
        print "In2 on"

    def __offIn1(self):
        GPIO.output( self.__in1Pin, False )
        print "In1 off"

    def __offIn2(self):
        GPIO.output( self.__in2Pin, False )
        print "In2 off"
```

Comment: If I'm not late I posted a answer yesterday that should fit your question

Answer (score 5):

If you trust `RPi.GPIO` library, I think it is a good stating point, you can [`patch` it by `unittest.mock` framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch). `patch` `RPi.GPIO.output` give to you the possibility to break the dependency from HW and sense the calls to that function.

That could be your test class

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, call
from my_module import MoterManager

@patch("RPi.GPIO.output", autospec=True)
class TestMoterManager(unittest.TestClass):
    in1Pin=67
    in2Pin=68

    def test_init(self, mock_output):
        """If you would MoterManager() stop motor when you build it your test looks like follow code"""
        mm = MoterManager(self.in1Pin,self.in1Pin)
        mock_output.assert_has_calls([call(self.in1Pin, False),call(self.in2Pin, False)],any_order=True)

    def test_stop(self, mock_output):
        mm = MoterManager(self.in1Pin,self.in1Pin)
        mock_output.reset_mock
        mm.stop()
        mock_output.assert_has_calls([call(self.in1Pin, False),call(self.in2Pin, False)],any_order=True)

    def test_brake(self, mock_output):
        mm = MoterManager(self.in1Pin,self.in1Pin)
        mock_output.reset_mock
        mm.stop()
        mock_output.assert_has_calls([call(self.in1Pin, True),call(self.in2Pin, True)],any_order=True)

    def test_rotateClockwise(self, mock_output):
        mm = MoterManager(self.in1Pin,self.in1Pin)
        mock_output.reset_mock
        mm.stop()
        mock_output.assert_has_calls([call(self.in1Pin, True),call(self.in2Pin, False)],any_order=True)

    def test_rotateCounterClockwise(self, mock_output):
        mm = MoterManager(self.in1Pin,self.in1Pin)
        mock_output.reset_mock
        mm.stop()
        mock_output.assert_has_calls([call(self.in1Pin, False),call(self.in2Pin, True)],any_order=True)
```

Few notes:

- In python-2.7 use `mock` available by `pip` instead of `unittest.mock`
- I'm using `autospec=True` almost in every test if you are wondering why take a look [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing)
- My tests should raise almost 1 bug in your code: typo in `brake` method